# Detect if specific Python.app instance is already running

Tags: python, objective-c, macos, cocoa, pyobjc

I am experimenting with OS X apps written in Python and need to detect if there is already an instance of Python.app running with certain script. The script modifies `CFBundleName` on-the-fly from `Python` to `MyApp` to change the app title in the menubar.

```
bundle = NSBundle.mainBundle()
info = bundle.localizedInfoDictionary() or bundle.infoDictionary()
info['CFBundleName'] = 'MyApp'
```

If I start another instance and check `CFBundleName` of the running apps, it will only tell me the original value, i.e. `Python`:

```
for app in NSWorkspace.sharedWorkspace().runningApplications():
    bundle = NSBundle.bundleWithURL_(app.bundleURL())
    info = bundle.localizedInfoDictionary() or bundle.infoDictionary()
    name = info.get('CFBundleName')
    if name in ('Python', 'MyApp'):
        print name  # => prints Python
```

So I need to find a way to mark a Python.app instance that runs MyApp script to be able to abort launching duplicate instances.

Is there such way?

**Update:**

Until there is a better solution, I'll be using `lockf`

```
import fcntl
lockfile = open('/tmp/myapp.lock', 'w')
fcntl.lockf(lockfile, fcntl.LOCK_EX | fcntl.LOCK_NB)
```

**Update 2:**

Well, I still need to find my application to focus. Currently, I just loop through all Python.app instances and focus them one by one. Normally, there is just one, but if there are few of them it can be messy.

```
from Foundation import NSWorkspace
from Cocoa import NSApplicationActivateAllWindows, NSApplicationActivateIgnoringOtherApps

try:
    import fcntl
    lockfile = open('/tmp/myapp.lock', 'w')
    fcntl.lockf(lockfile, fcntl.LOCK_EX | fcntl.LOCK_NB)

except IOError as e:
    assert (e.errno, e.strerror) == (35, 'Resource temporarily unavailable')

    for app in NSWorkspace.sharedWorkspace().runningApplications():
        if app.bundleIdentifier() == 'org.python.python':
            app.activateWithOptions_(NSApplicationActivateAllWindows | NSApplicationActivateIgnoringOtherApps)
    exit()
```

**Update 3:**

I am going to use a pid file until a better solution comes up

```
LOCK_FILE = '/tmp/myapp.lock'
PID_FILE = '/tmp/myapp.pid'

try:
    import fcntl
    # NOTE: needs to be assigned to a variable for the lock to be preserved
    lockfile = open(LOCK_FILE, 'w')
    fcntl.lockf(lockfile, fcntl.LOCK_EX | fcntl.LOCK_NB)

except IOError as e:    
    try:
        with open(PID_FILE) as f:
            pid = int(f.read())
    except:
        pid = None

    for app in NSWorkspace.sharedWorkspace().runningApplications():
        if app.bundleIdentifier() == 'org.python.python':
            if not pid or pid == app.processIdentifier():
                app.activateWithOptions_(NSApplicationActivateAllWindows | NSApplicationActivateIgnoringOtherApps)
    exit()

from Foundation import NSProcessInfo
info = NSProcessInfo.processInfo()
pid = info.processIdentifier()
with open(PID_FILE, 'w+') as f:
    f.write(str(pid))
```

Comment: Mailing list thread https://groups.google.com/d/topic/comp.lang.python/5X5cYeHe2Q0/discussion

Comment: Trying to reach osx dev crowd http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30703813/how-to-identify-mark-os-x-app-instance

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to solve this. Among them:

- libunique - a library specifically designed for this
- dbus - internal communications system

Many of them are described in the answers of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2261997/how-can-i-detect-what-other-copy-of-python-script-is-already-running).

A recipe for unique instances is given [here](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/474070/).

Comment: Thanks for the link! I believe there must be more options since I can reach OS X application API via PyObjC, and they may be easier to use.

Comment: I've added another recipe to the answer above.

Comment: I started to use `lockf` to prevent multiple instances, but I still need to focus on the already running instance, so I still need to identify it somehow.

Answer (score 0):

A less subtle solution would be to call `killall` with the name of your application without `.app` from the command line. This can be done from within you Python script using `os.command()`.

Comment: It can kill unrelated instances and I need just the exact copies. Also, there may be some status in the older instances so the task is to prevent starting another instance not killing the running ones.

Comment: If you can keep track of PID's, regular `kill` might be of use.